# Passing a variable to the React useCallback hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a difficult time learning React hooks.

I'm following along on this website, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

```
const onGameOver = React.useCallback(
  ({ playerScore, playerHealth, gameId }) => {
    setPages(player =>
      arrayMove(playerScore, playerHealth, gameId)
    );
    console.log('gameId: ', gameId);
  },
  [player, gameId]
);
```

I can see the playerScore and the playerHealth, but not gameId.

I put 'gameId' in my dependency array, but it's always 'undefined' in the console.log.

For testing purposes, I'm just giving gameId a dummy ID like this:

```
const gameId = useState(123);
```

But eventually, I will use it like this:

```
<GameOverScreen controlId={ControlId} stats={endGameStats} onGameOver=({onGameOver, gameId}) />
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: show the code when you use `onGameOver`

Comment: How are you calling `onGameOver`? possibly a confusion passing the parameters

Comment: Is `gameId` defined in the lines above this one? Or is it one you intend to pass in when calling `onGameOver`? Either way, as the others have said we need to see the surrounding code to advise you.

Comment: @NicholasTower I added the code where I set gameId.  Right now, I'm just using it with a test ID. thanks

Comment: I think you should learn about scoping, gameId is a parameter passed to the function, if you want to see the closure gameId then remove it from parameters that are passed to it: `React.useCallback(
  ({ playerScore, playerHealth }) => {`

Comment: @HMR well, now I see it, but it's odd because it shows it as an array, like this: gameId:  (2) [123, ƒ]   ... when have the value set as '123'

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell that's because `useState(123)` returns an array - `[value, updateFn]`, where `updateFn` is a function you can call to change the value of that particular piece of state. Change your definition from `const gameId = useState(1234);` to `const [gameId, updateGameId] = useState(1234);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updating in response to your edits**:

You added `const gameId = useState(123);` but that isn't quite right. `useState` returns an array with the state value, and a function that can be called to update that state. Typically you should do this:

```
const [gameId, setGameId] = useState(123)
```

And then you added this:

```
<GameOverScreen ... onGameOver=({onGameOver, gameId}) />
```

But that isn't valid JSX. To set a prop on a component, you either need to put it in quotes like `<MyComponent message="Hello"/>` or in curly braces like `<MyComponent gameId={gameId}/>`. Parentheses don't work. Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with a value like `{onGameOver, gameId}`... If you are trying to pass those two things as props, it should be more like

```
<GameOverScreen ... onGameOver={onGameOver} gameId={gameId} />
```

---

**Original Answer**

Imagine your function in isolation:

```
function actualOnGameOver({ playerScore, playerHealth, gameId }) {
  setPages(player =>
    arrayMove(playerScore, playerHealth, gameId)
  );
  console.log('gameId: ', gameId);
}
```

Look at all of the things that are referenced by the function, and determine where they come from:

- `setPages` - from outside the function (I'm guessing from a `useState` call)
- `arrayMove` - from outside the function (I'm guessing from an `import`)
- `playerScore` - received as an argument
- `playerHealth` - received as an argument
- `gameId` - received as an argument

Note that `useCallback` is a convenience version of `useMemo`, i.e. it's making/getting a cached version of your function. The dependencies array is used to tell React when it should invalidate that cache. Any non-constant values referenced by the function that come from outside the function should be mentioned in that array. Values received as arguments to the function (e.g. `gameId`) shouldn't go in there.

So your dependencies array should be `[setPages]` (or `[setPages, arrayMove]` if my guess about arrayMove being an import was wrong) because that is the only non-constant value referenced by the function that wasn't passed in as an argument.

When you pass the `actualOnGameOver` into `useCallback`, the result is a function with the same signature, so you would call `onGameOver` the same way, e.g.

```
onGameOver({
  playerScore: 100,
  playerHealth: 75,
  gameId: 'abc123'
})
```

Once you fix your dependency array, if `gameId` is still undefined, you should look into the code outside of your `onGameOver` function. Make sure when you call `onGameOver` you are passing a value for `gameId`.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I've added a bit of code to my original question that demonstrates how I wish to eventually use 'onGameOver'.  When I added all the parameters like you show above, it doesn't like the opening parenthesis.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell ok, I updated my answer to address the new info you added

Comment: I think I'm getting closer.  In my return statement where I return <GameOverScreen>, the value of gameId changes based on the game. I can see this when I debug.  However when ever I do my console.log inside the onGameOver callback, it's always the test value of '123'. I think that's because of a re-render.

Answer (score 4):

The `gameId` in the dependencies array is not the same value inside the function when it is invoked. This is because your function definition destructures `gameId` out of the first argument passed to it:

```
                                                                   vvvvvv
const onGameOver = React.useCallback(({ playerScore, playerHealth, gameId }) => {
```

This will "shadow" the value of `gameId` *outside* of the function passed to `React.useCallback()`.

The dependencies array passed to `React.useCallback()` are *not* implicitly passed to the function being created. The array is used to determine whether or not the function passed to `React.useCallback()` on that particular render should replace the function memoized by React* - Remember, `React.useCallback()` is roughly equivalent to:

```
React.useMemo(() => f, deps)
```

You will either have to pass `gameId` to `onGameOver` when it is executed, like this:

```
onGameOver({ gameId: .... })
```

Or you will need to remove `gameId` from the destructuring assignment:

```
const onGameOver = React.useCallback(({ playerScore, playerHealth }) => {
```

The latter is *probably* the correct approach, since this way `onGameOver` will always have the correct value for `gameId` without having the callers needing to know about it.

---

* The dependency array is necessary because the hooks themselves are called on every render, but we may want to keep some values stable across different renders.

Each render, each element in the `deps` array is compared with the `deps` array from the previous render. If any of them have changed, then the hook is marked as 'stale' and some kind of effect will take place, depending on the hook:

- `useMemo(f, deps)` will execute the function `f` and the return value of that function will be provided as the return value of `useMemo()` on this current render *and* subsequent renders until `deps` changes again.
- `useCallback()` is a wrapper around `useMemo()` that is slightly easier to use when intending to memoize a function. `useCallback(f, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => f, deps)`.
- `useEffect(f, deps)` and `useLayoutEffect(f, deps)` will *both* execute `f` when the dependency array changes, although *when* these functions are executed will differ based on which hook you use. You should use `useLayoutEffect()` if you need to interact with the DOM, otherwise you should use `useEffect()`.

This is why an empty array in place of the `deps` array will lead to an effect only being executed once for the components lifecycle - Because the arrays values will never change, so the effect will never be re-run.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to see gameId into useCallback deps array. I think you dont have to put on it the function parameters, but only variables (props or useState values) used inside the definition of the function.

To answer to your question it depends of the params passing on onGameOver function when you call it.